Why does Kestrel shut down while uploading an image?
I'm running an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with EF Core, MariaDb, SixLabors.ImageSharp 3.1.5 on IIS out-of-process on Plesk. I have configured global exception handling middleware and it's called before the endpoints.
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");

if (app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
   app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
   app.UseSwagger();
   app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

My issue is that for the image my, nice, image.jpg, every time I upload it from both Chromium based or Gecko based browser on the production server, I see that the application is shutting down.
This is very weird for me because

the upload and response seems to resume where it left of
it all happens within less than a second and I know that starting the server takes longer than that
it doesn't happen on local environment or during integration testing
even if I rename the image, the "application is shutting down..." persists.

Here is the log with debugging enabled:
(Mmt.Api.Services.Image.ImageCleanupService) [00:47:29 DBG ] Resized image my, nice, image.jpg
(Mmt.Api.Services.Image.ImageOperationsService) [00:47:31 DBG ] Connection id "0HN8QVRQ03JUP" accepted.
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections) [00:47:31 DBG ] Connection id "0HN8QVRQ03JUP" started.
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections) [00:47:31 INF ] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://127.0.0.1:25260/iisintegration - null 0
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics) [00:47:31 INF ] Application is shutting down...
(Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) [00:47:31 DBG ] Hosting stopping
(Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host) [00:47:31 DBG ] Connection id "0HN8QVRQ03JUP" completed keep alive response.
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections) [00:47:31 INF ] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://127.0.0.1:25260/iisintegration - 202 0 null 1.7087ms
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics) [00:47:31 DBG ] Connection id "0HN8QVRQ03JUP" disconnecting.
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections) [00:47:31 DBG ] Connection id "0HN8QVRQ03JUP" stopped.
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections) [00:47:31 DBG ] Connection id "0HN8QVRQ03JUP" sending FIN because: "The Socket transport's send loop completed gracefully."
(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets) [00:47:35 INF ] Uploaded image D:\vhosts\mmt\uploads\images\2024-12\my-nice-image-qfrckw.webp
(Mmt.Api.Services.Image.ImageOperationsService) [00:47:35 DBG ] Created thumb for my, nice, image.jpg
(Mmt.Api.Services.Image.ImageOperationsService) [00:47:35 INF ] Uploaded image D:\vhosts\mmt\uploads\thumbs\2024-12\my-nice-image-qfrckw.webp

So, my question is as per title: why is the application shutting down during this image upload?
To be more specific:

Could I have misconfigured something in Plesk when setting up out-of-process? If so, why does the application shut down only during uploading of this image?
Is it a known exception with ImageSharp? If so, why isn't this caught by the global exception handling middleware? It's part of a request and if it's an unhandled exception it should appear there.
Is this normal behavior from Kestrel? If so, again, why is it happening only for this image?

Should you need code snippets, please let me know.

Does it work for other images? Is it just this one image that causes the issue?

Maybe an OutOfMemoryException? Are there any logs in the Windows Event Viewer?

That's a very graceful shutdown, POST http://127.0.0.1:25260/iisintegration is politely asking your process to restart. Your app completes the current request, then stops. Maybe you hit a soft memory limit while processing the image?

@mjwills, yes it works for other images.

@Charlieface I could only see the Plesk logs, as it runs on a managed server. I couldn't find any errors in those logs though.

@JeremyLakeman, thanks for the explanation attempt. I'm still puzzled because this particular image is just 300Kb. I've uploaded larger ones and didn't have this issue. Additionally, if it would have been a soft memory limit shouldn't I have seen an exception for it?

Nothing actually failed. It never actually failed to allocate memory from the OS or crashed. The parent hosting process decided to recycle your process, check there for any logs or limits you might have reached.

What are the dimensions of this image? Can you share it with us?

@JeremyLakeman thanks for the tip regarding recycling. I can't get those logs but this makes sense to me, so I will consider this the answer.

@mjwills here is the image for which it the process keeps being recycled in production. https://imgur.com/a/5myDb37 Since it's just a recycle, I won't pursue the issue further.

So if you download that image from imgur it is the exact same size as your original file?
